# Eurostar - Is return ticket valid if I miss the first leg?

Tags: cancellations, eurostar, hidden-city-ticketing

I want to book a one-way ticket on the Eurostar (Paris-London) but I see that if I book a round-trip, the price will be lower.

I am curious if I book the round-trip but only take the return leg, that my ticket will be cancelled. I am not sure if they ensure that every passenger booked on the train actually board it, and cancel the tickets of those who did not.

How does it work in that case?

Comment: If you have any doubt, book the part you're interested in as the first leg, and you'll be left with an unused return. Which, depending on the fare, you might even be able to exchange for the time you actually need it! I'm a bit curious, though: there are a few fares where the roundtrip is cheaper than two one-way tickets, but are there really return tickets cheaper than a one-way **on the same train, in the same class**?

Comment: @jcaron I ended up doing that. And in that specific case, the round trip was cheaper than a one-way by 10 euros. Weird but I guess that's a limit of revenue optimisation techniques.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Eurostar conditions of carriage](http://www.eurostar.com/uk-en/conditions-carriage) do not mention this, and [this thread on flyertalk (dating from 2010)](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/european-rail-travel/1050749-eurostar-non-use-outbound-ticket-considered-two-oneways.html) seems to argue that **you can use just the return journey without taking the outward train**. According to several users, return tickets are treated like two singles and are therefore independent.

Answer (score 3):

On the eurostar FAQ:

https://help.eurostar.com/faq/us-en/question/If-the-traveller-doesn-t-use-their-outbound-ticket-can-they-use-the-return-ticket

**If the traveller doesn't use their outbound ticket, can they use the return ticket?**

*Yes as long as you leave the outbound journey alone and in a Live status in your GDS, the passenger can use the inbound ticket.*